# Scrapy: what's the best way to use itemloader i.c.w. a Postgres Pipeline?

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I'm trying to use the itemLoader to give empty items in Scrapy a default value, like this in items.py:

```
prod_specs = Field(
    default=[],
    input_processor=MapCompose(unicode_to_str, strip_tabs_new_lines),
)
```

So if prod_specs is not set, it should give it an empty object. But it's not working. If I try to store the fields into the database with `item['prod_specs'].`

I receive an error telling me the key not exists:

```
exceptions.KeyError: 'prod_specs'
```

Same for other fields if they're not set. I think the fact that I'm using `item['prod_specs']` and not the itemLoader as in items.py, is causing the error. But I'm not sure.

So what do you guys think? And do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: the official documentation seems outdated and the Field default value does not work anymore (see https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/560).
So another option is to use the pipeline to assign default values to an item:

```
def parse_item(self, item, spider):
    if "prod_specs" not in item: item['prod_specs'] = []
    return item
```

or during the psycopg2 insert:

```
def parse_item(self, item, spider):
    cur.execute("insert into mytable(prod_specs) values(%s)",
                item.get('prod_specs',[]))
    return
```

---

You're trying to use an ItemLoader as an Item.
Here's how to setup your items and itemloader.

items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose

class Product(Item):
    prod_specs = Field(
        default=[],
        input_processor=MapCompose(unicode_to_str, strip_tabs_new_lines)
    )
```

spider/myspider.py

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import Product

def parse(self, response):
    l = MyLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    l.add_xpath('prod_specs', '//div[@class="prod_specs"]')
    return l.load_item()
```

If you intend to use a lot of different items, you should subclass ItemLoader and define default processors.

Is that enough to answer your question ? You mentioned you wanted to write a Postgres pipeline. What I found to be the easiest is to use SQLAlchemy, this way you can write as many objects to as many databases as you want with a single pipeline.

Comment: I already did that part, but the problem now is to save those information inside PostgreSQL. I'm using psycopg2, working well so far. But I'm using item to save the data: ```def process_item(self, item, spider):``` and then ```item['prod_specs']``` If that item is empty it doesn't save an empty array but returns an error. That's why I think I need to use the ItemLoader inside the pipeline as well, am I correct?

Comment: Ok, then, in the pipeline, you can add `if "prod_specs" not in item: item['prod_spec'] = []` before the insert, or `cur.execute('insert into my_table(prod_specs) values(%s)', (item['prod_specs'] if 'prod_specs' in item else []))` during the insert.

Comment: but what's the purpose of the Itemloader default method if I have to do a check or the item is not empty????

Comment: My bad, looks like we have been misled by the official documentation: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/560. So, in this case, I would use the pipeline to load default values.